# Passing a variable with ajax from JS to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to pass a gps coordinate from JavaScript to a php variable on the same page, but after the script ran, and trying to echo in **php**, it doesn't show me anything (Notice: Undefined index: lat).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="gps"></p>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("gps");
var y=document.getElementById("gps");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
 x=position.coords.latitude;
  y=position.coords.longitude;
$.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'index.php', 
    data: { lat: x },
});
</script>
```

PHP code :

```
 echo "<script> getLocation(); </script>";
        $lat=$_POST['lat'];
        echo $lat;
```

How do I pass a variable from Javascript to php?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between client-side code and server-side code.  In particular, you need to understand what an HTTP request means.

Comment: Did you load the jquery library ? I can't see it in your code. $.ajax is a [jquery](http://jquery.com) function.

Comment: AJAX doesn't work like that, you're not suppose to echo any JS function. You simply want to call the function showPosition() from the js and then fetch the posted value in the backend. Use if isset to check if it's actually there, it's easy with the ternary operator. I don't have time to give a full working example here but this question has been answered over 1000 times on the internet, even a few answers on SO will give you full working code.

Comment: Agreed with @Jonast92 - You need to use the Jquery AJAX .complete function to handle returns. You should just echo the lat through PHP for this test. If you aren't sure if PHP is receiving the data like you want it, try running die(var_export($_POST)); as the first line of your PHP. [JQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load the jQuery library :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Insert the above `<script>` tag after `<head>`.
Because [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is a jQuery function, you must first load jQuery to use it.

You also need to close the `showPosition` function and do something with the returned data with `complete`:

```
function showPosition(position){
 x=position.coords.latitude;
 y=position.coords.longitude;
 $.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'index.php', 
    data: { lat: x },
    complete: function(text){ return text; }
 });
}
```

And it's not a nice option to call **javascript** function from **AJAX** response. So I would call the getLocation() function in **complete** value function of **$.ajax** :

```
function showPosition(position){
     x=position.coords.latitude;
     y=position.coords.longitude;
     $.ajax({  
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php', 
        data: { lat: x },
        complete: function(text){getLocation();return text;}
     });
}
```

Comment: You should also mention the .complete function - He's currently not handling the returned data properly in JS.

Comment: The OP might be trying to fire the getLocation function? Add document ready perhaps with that in?

Comment: In that case, the `complete:` line should read `complete: function(text){getLocation(text);}`. I realize his getLocation doesn't have an argument, but it only makes sense to pass the returned AJAX value instead of doing something else (since it isn't available elsewhere).

Comment: @matcarlson Yes, it should be like that. But there is no argument on **getLocation** and I think he is trying to save the location got from javascript to the server. That makes sense because he is calling **showPosition** in **getLocation**.

Comment: Thanks all the helps guys:) Updated the code, but sadly i still couldnt get the x variable to the server. At the first try the return text gave me an [Object object] answer at the top of my site, but not the php gave me that.

Comment: and i want to execute the javascirpt when a button is pressed on my site, that why I echoed: "echo "<script> getLocation(); </script>";"